# Error345: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

I am trying to send a POST request to a google cloud function. I am receiving the error

```
Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

.
I am using the POSTMAN Application to send the POST Requests.

Here is my code

```
def trade_stock(request):
    
    my_data = request.get_json()

    api.submit_order(
        my_data['symbol'], # Replace with the ticker of the stock you want to buy
        my_data['quantity'],
        my_data['side'],
        'market', 
        'gtc' # Good 'til cancelled
    )
    return {
        'Code' : 'Successful'
    }
```

To launch the target function I am using the command

```
functions-framework --target trade_stock --debug
```

This is the code I am using to send my request on POSTMAN

```
payload = {
    'symbol' : 'AAPL',
    'quantity' : '5',
    'side' : 'buy'
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}
```

And from there I am using POSTMAN to send the request with these parameters to the URL established the `functions-framework` command.

I have been struggling for a long time with this, any advice is much appreciated on how to fix this error.

***EDIT1****

After running

`request.is_json` a value of
`True` is returned

Comment: Have you done `print(request)` to see what you're getting?  Is it an object?  Is it the text of the POST request?  What JSON is saying is that it's not JSON.

Comment: The error simply means that at some point the code expected data in JSON format but got something different.

Comment: `print(request)` returns `<Request 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/?symbol=%22AAPL%22&quantity=%225%22&side=%22buy%22' [POST]>
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2022 17:02:48] "POST /?symbol=%22AAPL%22&quantity=%225%22&side=%22buy%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt do you know how I would fix that, I set the `Content-Type` to `application/json`

Comment: Also @TimRoberts `print(type(request)` returns `flask.wrappers.Request`

Comment: That doesn't look like a POST request.  It looks like a GET request (all the variables are in the URL), and of course those are never JSON.  Are you asking Postman to send a POST?

Comment: first you could check `print( response.text )` to see what you get from server. maybe it sends HTML with error message.

Comment: @TimRoberts @furas I was able to get what I needed using `request.args`. thanks for your help